# Como ejecutar una función varias veces en mounted Vue 3

Tags: vue.js

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un request completo por paginación al inicio de la pagina para obtener todos los resultados del request, para lo cual estoy utilizando mounted para llamra a la fucnion.

El problema que tengo que solo se ejecuta una vez, cabe decir que la función que estoy utilizando es una función asíncrona, la cual consume un servicio desde otro archivo, el cual envía datos a través de una paginación, por lo que necesito incrementar el número de la pagina cada vez que se obtenga un resultado

hasta aquí lo que he realizado

```
methods: {
    async chargeData() {
        let allPages = 1;
        let res = [];
        let results = [];
        try {
            res = await ProductService.getProductsFromCarousel(allPages, false, false, false, this.idCategory);
            console.log(res);
            results = results.concat(res);
            console.log(results);
            allPages++;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
},
mounted() {
        this.chargeData();
},
```

Solo he logrado que se ejecute una vez y lo que necesito es que el contador allPages se incremente hasta llegar al limite de peticiones.

Alguna idea de como llamar ala función chargeData para que se ejecute n veces

Comment: Los bucles ofrecen una forma rápida y sencilla de hacer algo repetidamente. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Bucles_e_iteraci%C3%B3n

Comment: esa fue mi primera opción pero no conozco el limite de las paginas para utilizar un for, si utlizo un for contra que lo comparo

Comment: Y quien conoce el límite entonces?

Comment: son limites dinámicos, al final se esta enviando un id de categoría cada categoría puede tener desde 1 a n paginas

Comment: Si tu no lo sabes, y la api/servicio que consumes no te devuelve cual es el número total de páginas, o sea el valor de lo que llamas `n`, no hay forma de "llamar ala función chargeData para que se ejecute n veces"

Comment: También puedes usar un while, que dependiendo de la respuesta de la api, la condición pase a false